# sql decode case when

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

```
decode (case when sd='N' and sr_corp_support='0' then sr_corp_agree else null end, '1','0','0','1','') as sr_corp_agree,
```

hi I am having trouble understanding this code
it seems to me when some statement is 1, we get 0
&
when some statement is 0, we get 1

but I am not too sure how exactly

could you help to explain how to interpret the case when statement into is 0 or 1

thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Decode is a product specific function.)

Comment: oracle sql developer

Answer (score 0):

This:

```sql
decode(
  case when sd='N' and sr_corp_support='0' then sr_corp_agree else null end,
  '1','0',
  '0','1',
  ''
) as sr_corp_agree
```

Can be rewritten as:

```sql
CASE
WHEN sd='N' AND sr_corp_support='0' AND sr_corp_agree = '1'
THEN '0'
WHEN sd='N' AND sr_corp_support='0' AND sr_corp_agree = '0'
THEN '1'
ELSE NULL -- Same as ''
END AS sr_corp_agree
```

In English: If the `sd` and `sr_corp_support` column values are `N` and `0`, respectively, then if `sr_corp_agree` is `1` or `0` then output the opposite `0` or `1`, respectively, and for any other `sd`, `sr_corp_support` or `sr_corp_agree` values output an empty string (which, in Oracle, is identical to `NULL`).